# Convert 37.818 into base 10

Tags: radix, octal, base-conversion

```
3 x 8^1 = 24
7 x 8^0= 7

8 x 8^-1 = 1
1 x 8^-2 = 0.015625

(24+7 ) . (1.015625) = 32.015625
```

I'm trying to convert octal to base 10 i know there is problem with my first decimal. Should i stop at 8 x 8^-1??

Comment: its supposed to be (37.81)base 8

Comment: 37.818 is not octal. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

37.81 is not octal. Can only use 0 through 7.